# Why is $\frac{1}{n\alpha(n)}\int_{\partial B(0,1)}\frac{1-|x|^2}{|x-y|^n}dS(y)=\int_{B(0,1)}G(x,y)dy$

Tags: partial-differential-equations, greens-function

> Why is $$\frac{1}{n\alpha(n)}\int_{\partial B(0,1)}\frac{1-|x|^2}{|x-y|^n}dS(y)=\int_{B(0,1)}G(x,y)dy$$ where $G$ is the Green function and defined as(in the unit ball) $G(x,y):=\Phi(y-x)-\Phi(|x|(y-\frac{x}{|x|^2}))$ and $\Phi$ is the fundamental solution of the Poisson equation for the dimension $n\ge 3$, i.e. $\Phi(x)=\frac{1}{n(n-2)\alpha(n)}\frac{1}{|x|^{n-2}}$

I think I have to use first Green formula,

$\int_B \Delta f=\int_{\partial B}Df\cdot n\ dS$

what is $n$ here ?, $\frac{y}{|y|}$ ?

If $Df\cdot n=\frac{1-|x|^2}{|x-y|^n}$ then I have to find $Df$ and apply the Laplace operator to verify the formula but how do I get $Df$ ?

Comment: $n$ is the unit normal vector on the boundary.

Comment: @XianjinYang so in my case it is $\frac{y}{|y|}$ ?

Comment: yes.  you can use the green formula to calculate it.

Comment: @XianjinYang if $\frac{1-|x|^2}{|x-y|^{n}}$ corresponds to $Df\cdot n$ how do I get $Df$ ?

Comment: You cannot directly match terms in the Green formula with the result you want to prove. You can start from the right hand side and substitute the formula for $G(x,y)$ and  integrate by parts and use divergent theorem or green formula to get the left hand side.